# Highest 4 Numbers From Array #1 To Store In Another Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

So I have three different arrays involved here...

I'm looping through golferThreeIcons (NSMutableArray), and I'm trying to take the highest 4 results (golferThreeIcons contains #'s as strings) and store them into the topFourIconsNum (NSMutableArray) and then I plan to store the id of that highest number in the array topFourIconsId (NSMutableArray).

One tricky thing is that golferThreeIcons start out at 99, but I want that to act like zero. So the number 99 should not get added to either of the arrays...

Example: 
golferThreeIcons {2,1,5,3,9}

And after the loop went through I want it to show something like this...

topFourIconsId {0,2,3,4} --- 0 corresponds to 2 in golferThreeIcons --- 2 corresponds to 5 in golfer three icons

topFourIconsNum {2,5,3,9} ----(in any order as long as it corresponds to the top four icons id)

```
NSMutableArray *topFourIconsId = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"0", @"0", @"0", @"0", @"0" ,nil];
NSMutableArray *topFourIconsNum = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"0", @"0", @"0", @"0", @"0" ,nil];
int *ids = 0;
                for (NSString *s in golferThreeIconCounter) {
                    if(s != @"0") {
                        int sint = [s intValue];
                        int *idn = 0;
                        for(NSString *n in topFourIconsNum) {
                            int nint= [n intValue];
                            if(sint == 99 && nint == 0) {
                                NSString *idstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ids];
                                NSString *sintstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sint];
                                [topFourIconsId replaceObjectAtIndex:idn withObject:idstring];
                                [topFourIconsNum replaceObjectAtIndex:idn withObject:sintstring];
                                NSLog(@"IN %@",sintstring);
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                if (sint > nint) {
                                    NSString *idstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ids];
                                    NSString *sintstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sint];
                                    [topFourIconsId replaceObjectAtIndex:idn withObject:idstring];
                                    [topFourIconsNum replaceObjectAtIndex:idn withObject:sintstring];
                                    NSLog(@"IN %@",sintstring);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            idn++;
                        }
                    }
                    ids++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a crazy idea

Put your golferThreeIcons in a NSDictionary with the array index as the key and the array value as the value and then sort the keys on their value:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", @"1", @"5", @"3", @"9", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil]];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSLog([sortedKeys description]);
```